# Animação de carregamento

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

**Tenho um código que faz uma animação de carregamento antes de iniciar uma página.**

**css.css**

```
.preload{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:99999;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    opacity:1;
    background-color:#fff;
    /*background-image:url('https://38.media.tumblr.com/bec5933eea5043acf6a37bb1394384ab/tumblr_meyfxzwXUc1rgpyeqo1_400.gif');
    background-image:url('https://media.giphy.com/media/ugEWbEMH0gm2c/giphy.gif');*/
    background-image:url('https://media.giphy.com/media/l4FGmQ3Ddqsp8LKKY/giphy.gif');
    background-size:70%;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<div id="preload" class="preload"></div>
```

logo após a tag **body** tem essa div que faz o carregamento da animação.

**script.php**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#preload").fadeOut(1000);
      });
</script>
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Porquê quando mudo o .ready para . load a animação fica infinita?
E porque antes de carregar todas as imagens a animação some?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que o `document` não tem um evento `load`, apenas a `window`. Veja o snippet abaixo.

```js
$(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#preload').fadeOut(1000);
 });
```

```css
.preload{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:99999;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    opacity:1;
    background-color:#fff;
    /*background-image:url('https://38.media.tumblr.com/bec5933eea5043acf6a37bb1394384ab/tumblr_meyfxzwXUc1rgpyeqo1_400.gif');
    background-image:url('https://media.giphy.com/media/ugEWbEMH0gm2c/giphy.gif');*/
    background-image:url('https://media.giphy.com/media/l4FGmQ3Ddqsp8LKKY/giphy.gif');
    background-size:70%;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preload" class="preload"></div>
```

Quanto à sua dúvida do carregamento das imagens, a animação tem um tempo definido, passado como parâmetro para a função `fadeOut()`. Quando a página carrega, a animação é executada no tempo definido. Se desejar um tempo maior, aumente o valor do parâmetro de `1000`(tempo em ms) para a quantidade desejada.

**EDIÇÃO**

A partir da versão 3.0 do `jQuery`, houve uma mudança. Ao invés de usar `window.load()`, é necessário usar `window.on('load',function () { //... }`

Comment: Muito obrigado, não sabia que no document não tinha como usar .load(), do jeito que você deixou funciona, mas só com o jquery 2.1.1, eu uso o 3.3.1, e nele da loop. 
:/

Comment: @PedroHenrique, editado e resolvido. É sempre bom informar quais versões está utilizando. Se essa resposta resolveu seu problema, por favor, marque-a como solução.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou bem.